# CSS body full height but not scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React app that I created using `npx create-react-app`.  I've incorporated page animations and the source I used requires CSS to have

```
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

However, the body is not scrolling and it stops at the `footer`.  Here is my footer css.

```
footer {
  font-family: "Lucida Handwriting";
  text-align: center;
  background: #a1793a;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

If I remove the `height: 100%`, the body disappears. How do I fix this and make the body scroll?

Comment: Do you have any content in your body except the footer? If not, that will explain the "disappearing".BTW, with `position: relative` neither `bottom, left, or width` will have any effect, since they are the default settings. Also `flex-shrink` only makes sense if the element has a parent which has `display: flex`

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: auto` on the body/html/#root css ?

Comment: @QuentinGrisel it does not help

Comment: Ok well please add a repro on stackblitz/codepen so we can  se what's happening

Comment: @QuentinGrisel creating on CodePen doesn't show the problem.  This is the repo and npm I'm using with my React app https://github.com/Steveeeie/react-page-transition

Comment: However, we didn't understood what exactly is happening and what you are expecting. But if you want to ensure no scrolling then apply `overflow:hidden` on body tag with `height:100vh`. But if you want to make it scrollable, use `overflow:auto` with `min-height:100vh`. If you want your footer to be sticked at the bottom, you may add `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` on it with `bottom:0`. There are few more alternatives of doing it however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
html,
body,
#root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```